# openssl configuration issue which lets only root user correctly verify web server certificates

Tags: permissions, openssl, root

when I check the SSL certificate chain of a web server on my raspbian system, e.g. by running

```
openssl s_client -connect plumbr.eu:443
```

I get the following error output:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=3 C = SE, O = AddTrust AB, OU = AddTrust External TTP Network, CN = AddTrust External CA Root
verify error:num=19:self signed certificate in certificate chain
verify return:0
...
```

However, when i `sudo` the very same, then everything works fine:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=3 C = SE, O = AddTrust AB, OU = AddTrust External TTP Network, CN = AddTrust External CA Root
verify return:1
depth=2 C = GB, ST = Greater Manchester, L = Salford, O = COMODO CA Limited, CN = COMODO RSA Certification Authority
verify return:1
depth=1 C = GB, ST = Greater Manchester, L = Salford, O = COMODO CA Limited, CN = COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
verify return:1
depth=0 OU = Domain Control Validated, OU = PositiveSSL Wildcard, CN = *.plumbr.eu
verify return:1
...
```

The same goes for several other web sites I tested. I'm pretty sure that this is not the expected behaviour. Does someone know how to fix this, or at least a hint where to look? The search for existing solutions was unsuccesful so far.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: @jww yes you're totally right, but I didn't get an answer on askubuntu (part of stackexchange) which should be the perfect place... :-(

Comment: @TillKolditz - Try [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) or start a bounty at Ubuntu Stack Exchange. The [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) folks are very sharp. They will likely start looking at filesystem permissions. You should probably post them when you ask the question.

Comment: @oliv you are correct. When you repost your remark as an answer I can mark it as the solution.

Comment: @jww OK thanks I'll keep that in mind the next time :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the directory holding trusted certificates has read access for everybody.

On my system (ubuntu) the directory `/etc/ssl/certs` where `AddTrust_External_Root.pem` is located has read access:

```
$ ls -ld /etc/ssl/certs
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 24576 mar 14  2016 /etc/ssl/certs
```